# How to find an id in complex html code using Python's webdriver?

Tags: python, webdriver

In this complex html code, I would like to find the id="workContentWrapper" using Python's webdriver.

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body style="MARGIN: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f4f4f4" onkeydown="return onBodyKeyDown(event)" onkeypress="return onBodyKeyPress(event)" onclick="onBodyClick(event)" onload="main();" onunload="handleUnload(window);" onresize="null">
    <div>...</div>
    <div id="panesLoaded" isLoaded="true">
        <div>...</div>
        <div id="workPaneWrapper" style="WIDTH: 100%; MARGIN: 0px 0px 15px">
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border=0>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>...</td>
                        <td width="205" vAlign="top" style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f4f4f4" rowSpan="1" colSpan="1">
                            <iframe name="oLeftPaneContent" width="&{screenToggler.getSelectionPaneWidth()};%" height="600" title="null" id="oLeftPaneContent" src="campaign_sp_selection" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="HEIGHT: 690px; WIDTH: 205px; DISPLAY: block; VISIBILITY: visible" onload="this.title=oLeftPaneContent.document.title;">
                                <html>
                                    <head>...</head>
                                    <body tabIndex="-1" scroll="no" style="MARGIN:0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #f4f4f4" onkeydown="return onBodyKeyDown(event)" onekeypress="return onBodyKeyPress(event)" onclick="onBodyClick(event)" onload="main();" onunload="handleUnload(window); if (top.selectionMediator) top.selectionMediator = null;" onresize="null">
                                        <form>...</form>
                                        <iframe>...</iframe>
                                        <form name="oFormMain" id="oFormMain" onsubmit="return false" action="campaign_sp_selection" encType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
                                            <div>...</div>
                                            <div tabindex="0" id="workPaneWrapper" role="region" accessKey="s" style="WIDTH: 100%" aria-label="Selector">
                                                <table>...</table>
                                                <div id="workContentWrapper" style="BORDER-TOP: #7386ad 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #7386ad 1px solid; WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: #7386ad 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #7386ad 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6edf6">
                                                    <div id="workAreaWrapper" style="WIDTH: 100%; BORDER-BOTTOM: white 1px solid">
                                                        <table>...</table>
                                                        <div class="listContainer" id="campaignSPTreeWrapper" style="OVERFLOW: auto; HEIGHT: 574px; WIDTH: 100%">
                                                            <table width="" id="" border="" cellSpacing="" cellPadding="">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr id="" onclick="" ondbclick="" uid="" notMultiSelectable="true" selectable="true" isopen="false" isnode="true">
                                                                        <td class="tableItem" id="r0c0" noWrap="nowrap" style="PADDING-LEFT: 7px" rowSpan="1" colspan="1" iscell="true">
                                                                            <img class="treeNorgie" id="campaignSPTreer0Norg" onclick="campaignSPTree.onToggle('r0')" ondbclick="campaignSPTree.onToggleBranch('r0')" alt="Fermé(e)" src="/wfo/uif/images/norgie_deselected.gif?v=11.1.1.7673" border="0" />
                                                                            <a onkeydown="campaignSPTree.onKeyDown(this);" onclick="return false;" href="#r0" shape="">
                                                                                <span>
                                                                                    <label class="hidden-label">Tree level 0,1 of 3.</label>
                                                                                    <span id="r0c0Content" name="r0c0Content">
                                                                                        <img alt="" src="/wfo/bbm/images/icons/campaign.gif?v=11.1.1.7673" border="0" />SCO CE HMO N2
                                                                                    </span>
                                                                                    <label class="hidden-label" id="campaignSPTreer0ChildInfo" childInfo=", node has 98 items. Press the right arrow key to show/hide this row's child items.">.Ouvert(e), node has 98 items. Press the right arrow key to show/hide this row's child items.</label>
                                                                                </span>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div>...</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>                                               
                                        </form>
                                    </body>
                                </html>
                            </iframe>
                        </td>
                        <td>...</td>
                        <td>...</td>
                        <td>...</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wrote these few lines in Python of code yet simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

ie_options = Options()
ie_options.ignore_protected_mode_settings = True
ie_options.ensure_clean_session = True

browser = webdriver.Ie(options=ie_options)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
action = ActionChains(browser)

browser.get('http://xxxxxxxxx')
# Auto authentification
browser.find_element_by_id("spanLinkActiver").click()

#Click on tab "Forecasting and Scheduling"
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Forecasting and Scheduling')]").click()
browser.find_element_by_id("workPaneWrapper")
browser.find_element_by_id("workContentWrapper")

time.sleep(10)

browser.close()
```

At runtime I have the following error while the previous id "workPaneWrapper" is correctly found:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\ConnectToOpoci.py", line 26, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id('workContentWrapper')
  File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Applications\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with css selector == [id="workContentWrapper"]
```

Could you please help me understand why it doesn't work ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I continued my research and I may have a lead. There are 3 frames on my page. Is the id I'm looking for not in the right frame?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed the solution. I used the command to change the frame:

```
browser.switch_to.frame('oLeftPaneContent')
```